# mysqli query returns error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am building a user login form validation. On correct, password user will be able to go to user access area.
The error has occurred on the below line.

```
$query = mysqli_query ("select * from tb_cform where u_pass='$pass' AND u_username='$username' ",$connection);
```

The error I get is the following:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null

Comment: Your warning is generated when you call `mysqli_num_rows()` (or a function that calls it), not the one you're showing...

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$query = mysqli_query ("select * from tb_cform where u_pass='$pass' AND u_username='$username' ",$connection);
```

to:

```
$query = mysqli_query ($connection, "SELECT * FROM `tb_cform` WHERE `u_pass` = '$pass' AND `u_username` = '$username' ");
```

You need to pass the connection first. Wrapping table and column names in backticks will prevent mysql reserved words error. Also Selecting everything from a table is bad as it will reduce savety and speed.

Comment: How to pass the connection? Sorry for asking silly questions, I've just started php and sql

Comment: The variable `$connection` should be the connection

Comment: I have one more error. Undefined variable: pass  on this line $pass = stripslashes($pass);

Comment: Without any other code it's impossible  to answer that question. Second it's better to ask a second question about it.